# How can I disable the "double-click-to-copy" function?

Tags: copy-paste, click

On webpages, PDFs, and any other contents, macOS enables me to double-click the text to copy. It is annoying. How can I disable the "double-click-to-copy" function?

Comment: Double-click should highlight text, not necessarily copy it. Can you describe exactly what you're doing? I guess the other question is: "what are you trying to do with a double-click instead, which this behaviour obstructs?"

Comment: @benwiggy. It actually highlights the text but also copies the text.

Comment: Odd. Do you have BetterTouchTool installed on your Mac?

Comment: @IconDaemon. No

Comment: Are you using a mouse or a trackpad (or both?) Does this odd behavior happen if you use either?

Comment: @IconDaemon I use a mouse most of the time. It happens when using a mouse or a trackpad.

Comment: I can't reproduce the behaviour: selecting with a double click does not copy it. I've never heard of that being a thing. Are you sure you haven't installed some third-party app or extension that might be doing this?

Comment: @benwiggy I am not sure. It happens even I double-click the text in a PDF file opened by Adobe PDF Reader.

Comment: OK, so my earlier question, why are you double-clicking the text?

Comment: @benwiggy On overleaf, I need to locate the source code. On the PDF reader and webpages, I need to highlight them.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand the workflow, and why copying is a problem. You double click to locate source code in Overleaf? And you highlight (e.g. select text) in PDFs, and then.... what? Anyway, you ought to investigate whether you've got some software installed that is causing this.

Comment: @benwiggy Double-click-to-copy causes a problem when you have copied some content, and after double-clicking, the copied content is updated, and the old one is lost. Thank you. I will check the folder and see which software caused the issue.

Comment: Pls let us know if you find out what has been causing this behavior by updating your poster for example, even if you can not resolve it at first. I understand why this behavior would be undesirable for most users, but it might be useful at times, especially if it was possible to turn it on and off.

Comment: @Alper, I have not figured out the reason. The issue happens from time to time.